# Real world explanation of using ConfigureAwait to false in c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, c#-4.0, windows-runtime, async-await

I am learning async/await and I came across the blog in which it's mentioned about using ConfigureAwait with async/await. It read's like this:

**ConfigureAwait accepts a Boolean continueOnCapturedContext parameter: passing true means to use the default behavior, and passing false means that the system doesn’t need to forcefully marshal the delegate’s invocation back to the original context and can instead execute the delegate wherever the system sees fit.**

The information does not tell much in detail, can anybody explain the real world example of using it. I also searched further and found out that it should be used with HTTP calls and such, but didn't got concrete answer for why should we use it.

Reference link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsappdev/2012/04/24/diving-deep-with-winrt-and-await/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is useful for scenarios where a single thread handles multiple actions, think Dispatcher thread in WPF or the host thread in IIS.

It is most obvious in Asp.Net (on Windows and full .net, hosted in IIS) -> if you do not specify `.ConfigureAwait(false)` and the request takes a significant amount of time, no other requests can be processed by the same w3wp.exe process.

The whole app is essentially blocked.

What this is doing is saying that the control can return to this stack using another thread from the threadpool, essentially unblocking the main thread.

Comment: Thnx for the answer. But isn't the code running in the separate thread when it is async? Why should we than take care of ConfigureAwait.

Comment: The code is not running, async works by effectively not doing anything while waiting on IO operation (network, disk etc). The control is then returned to the line immediately following async, and THAT should happen on SOME thread. ConfigureAwait allows you to choose on which.

Comment: @Dishant No, as Stephen Toub points out [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/01/13/await-anything/) or elsewhere, **async** in and of itself has nothing to do with threads. As a design paradigm it can facilitate concurrency, but by default does not. Most basically, async can be thought of as a way to make sure that a *single* thread can always make forward progress, by circling back to do other pending work instead of blocking whenever that would otherwise occur.